# Internet Explorer Text Gradient

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is it possible to use an gradient on a text also in Internet Explorer?

```
<span class="test">HELLO WORLD</span>

.test {
    font-size:48px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243,197,189,1) 0%, rgba(232,108,87,1) 50%, rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%, rgba(255,102,0,1) 75%, rgba(199,34,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243,197,189,1) 0%,rgba(232,108,87,1) 50%,rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%,rgba(255,102,0,1) 75%,rgba(199,34,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(243,197,189,1) 0%,rgba(232,108,87,1) 50%,rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%,rgba(255,102,0,1) 75%,rgba(199,34,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3c5bd', endColorstr='#c72200',GradientType=0 );
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}
```

this works for me in Chrome but in IE you can only see a bar that hides the text

Comment: I don't dare to ask, but what version of IE would that be?

Comment: i work with IE11 i won't support lower versions